# Using If, elif, else, using formulas instead of print statements

Tags: python, if-statement

Someone in Stackoverflow answered my question which was brilliant, I need to replace the print statements with formulas.

The reason for this so I can convert the output to hours, minutes, seconds.

Having multiple print statements and the formula included I can not separate them.

I have three logics but just need to separate them into formulas like the print statement.

Original program:

```
T17 = input('?')

if T17 < 0:
     print("LOCAL SIDEREAL TIME",T17 + 24)

elif T17 > 24:
    print("LOCAL SIDEREAL TIME",T17 - 24)

else:
        print("LOCAL SIDEREAL TIME",T17)
```

---

This is what I am trying to do.

```
T17 = input('?')

if T17 < 0:

 T17 + 24

elif T17 > 24:

 T17 - 24

else:

 print("LOCAL SIDEREAL TIME",T17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you meant to re-assign the calculations back to `T17`:

```
T17 = input('?')
if T17 < 0:
    T17 = T17 + 24
elif T17 > 24:
    T17 = T17 - 24

print("LOCAL SIDEREAL TIME", T17)
```

Comment: Though T17 on the left hand side inside the if/elif blocks could be named anything so long as the arg name matches the name of the arg in the final print statement.

Comment: Very much appreciated, just learning and need that extra insight.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but I found [this source](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/computational-physics/) to be helpful starting out with computational python.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just trying to implement [modulo](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html):

```
>>> -10 % 24
14
>>> 34 % 24
10
>>> 16 % 24
16
```

So :

```
t17 = t17 % 24
```

should do fine.

Finally, be sure to check [Astropy](http://www.astropy.org/) if you're working on Astronomy with Python.